# Iterating through a sequence of mappings with different inputs with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to use one template to handle varying input files. I want to iterate through a specific sequence of mappings where the keys and the values in the sequence of mappings can change. I have a solution but it feels like a hack and it only works for the latest version of pandoc. Here is an example of the functionality I would like:

input1.md:

```
---
title: "Input 1"
links:
  - Pear: "https://pear.com/"
  - Banana: "https://banana.com/"
  - Grape: "https://grape.com/"
  - Strawberry: "https://strawberry.com/"
---

This is the body.
```

desired-output1.md:

```
Input 1

- Pear : https://pear.com/
- Banana : https://banana.com/
- Grape : https://grape.com/
- Strawberry : https://strawberry.com/

This is the body.
```

input2.md:

```
---
title: "Input 2"
links:
  - Kiwi: "https://kiwi.com/"
  - Lemon: "https://lemon.com/"
---

This is the body.
```

desired-output2.md:

```
Input 2

- Kiwi : https://kiwi.com/
- Lemon : https://lemon.com/

This is the body.
```

Here is the pandoc template I am using right now which works however it feels hacky and does not work with recent but older versions of pandoc:

template.md:

```
$title$

$for(links)$
$for(it/pairs)$
- $it.key$ : $it.value$
$endfor$
$endfor$

$body$
```

Here is the command I am using to compile the document:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t markdown --template=template.md input1.md
```

My question is: Is there a more straightforward, less of a hack way to achieve this functionality with one template file? Is there a way to ensure this works with older versions of pandoc? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a good and elegant solution to me. Why do you feel like it's a hack?

Comment: It works with recent versions >2.8 but not with 2.7.3 which is installed and called by RMarkdown's render() in the latest RStudio release.  2.7.3 is throwing an error - it doesn't like it piped to pairs :  $(it/pairs)$

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me in pandoc 2.7.3

In the YAML header -

```
---
title: "Frank Hermosillo"
image: "frank.jpg"
links:
  - site: Apple
    url: "https://apples.com/"
  - site: Pear
    url: "https://pears.com/"
  - site: Orange
    url: "https://oranges.com/"
```

There are two tabs before 'url:' and one before '- site':

And in the template:

```
        <ul class="list-inline">
          $for(links)$
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a href=$links.url$>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
                To $links.site$
              </button>
            </a>
          </li>
          $endfor$
        </ul>
```